# Android: static field set to null

Tags: android, static, singleton, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an Activity with a private static field. And that static field is set to null when I turn the screen. Of course, one would guess that Android kills the process, but I'm sure it does not. But let's begin from the beginning.

There is a JNI library whose functions may be called from only one thread. From Java, the library functions are visible as native methods of an object (by the way, only one instance of that object is meaningful, there will be only one instance of the library with its static structures). The library object is used via a wrapper, a Java layer providing read/write access locks. The activity has a private static field referencing that wrapped library object. The library performs a long operation on a separate thread.

The singleton creation was like the following. Since all activities are created on the same UI thread, in onCreate() I just checked if the field is null and if it is null, created a wrapped library object. There was no problem -- at least, on Android 2.x.

Now, on Android 4, the following happens: I start a long operation and turn the screen.
The activity is re-created, the savedInstanceState parameter in onCreate() is not null, but that private static field *is* null.
Now, a new library object is created, then a new wrapper is created with its new read/write lock, and then a library operation is invoked... of course, the library is still busy with the request initiated before turning the screen, the new read/write lock does not protect the old library, data get corrupt and everything crashes.

I have heard that a remedy to this would be to keep the reference not as a static field but as an instance field of the Application.

Now, the question is:

***WHY?*** ***What the hell is going on?*** *Do I have to rewrite all singletons?*

Comment: Determine first if Android is killing and recreating your process. This is simple to do. Add a log message in `onCreate()` of your activity. In the logcat output you can see the process ID of the process that is generating the message. Run the app, turn the screen and look at the logcat. You should see 2 log messages from `onCreate()`. Are the ProcessIDs the same?

Comment: To the possible remedy I can only say this: This won't help. a static field will only be reset if the process is recreated. If the process is recreated then your `Application` instance will also be relocated, so moving this reference from a static field to an instance of the `Application` will not help.

Comment: myPid is the same (printed from onCreate() on 1st creation and after turning the screen)

Comment: by the way, if the process was killed, the library would be unloaded and the long operation would be killed too.

Comment: The the only thing I can think of is that your native library is clobbering your static field or you have a bug in your code and you think the value is null when it isn't or you are setting it to null without knowing about it.

Comment: Yes, it was that simple... clean-up in onDestroy().